# CouchDB error: Latin character in JSON using cURL

Tags: json, curl, couchdb

I am trying to create a CouchDB document that contains Latin characters using cURL without success.

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:5984/example/1' -d '{"title":"There is Nóthing Left to Lose","artist":"Foo Fighters"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

The response is `{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}`.

However, the following works

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:5984/example/1' -d '{"title":"There is Nothing Left to Lose","artist":"Foo Fighters"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

The only difference is `ó` in `Nothing`.

Complete debug message:

```
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 5984 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x20a6050
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x20a6050) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5984 (#0)
> PUT /example/1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:5984
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 65
>
} [data not shown]
* upload completely sent off: 65 out of 65 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
* Server CouchDB/1.4.0 (Erlang OTP/R14B04) is not blacklisted
< Server: CouchDB/1.4.0 (Erlang OTP/R14B04)
< Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 13:38:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 48
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
<
{ [data not shown]
100   113  100    48  100    65   3000   4062 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 65000
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}

* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending JSON, so let the server know what you are sending. Just add this header with your curl command:

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

Also, add `-v` option to see the curl debug message. If above doesn't work, then show us the debug messages.

**Update::** I think the server faces problem while parsing the `JSON`. I don't much idea about this, but probably changing the `Nóthing` into `N&oacute;thing` or `N\u0443thing`.

Comment: That doesn't fix it. I suppose the error shows it already knows that it's JSON.

Comment: I added debug message. Thanks

Comment: Try `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` or your character set. It works with my test server.

Comment: I couldn't parse the json using a php code. So I believe that server faced the same issue. Please check my updated answer.